# Traefik proxy splitting dynamic config file

Tags: linux, reverse-proxy, configuration, yaml, traefik

i have questions about config files in Traefik. I would like to split my dynamic config file into multiples based services files.

**_ The setup**

I have a proxmox instance running a pfSense VM. All traffic is sent to the pfSense which then dispatch everything to right places if authorized. pfSense is also used as internal resolver for dns local names like: jenkins.sub-domain.domain.com, heimdall.sub-domain.domain.com, etc..
Finally, pfSense is running an openVPN server i'm using to access the "proxmox local network".
I have a VM running a traefik instance on docker. Just traefik, nothing more on this host.
I have a VM running services i want to be used only inside the local network (heimdall, jenkins, portainer, etc..)
Finally I have a VM running services i want to be accessed from outside (internet) (gitea, bookstack, wireguard, etc..)
I setup some dns for the ouside services like: gitea.mydomain.com, bookstack.mydomain.com, etc...

I redirect ports 80 & 443 to traefik proxy.

**_ Traefik setup**
Here are the config files:

**/home/user/traefik/docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
    
    services:
      traefik:
        image: traefik:latest
        container_name: "Traefik-Proxy"
        restart: unless-stopped
        security_opt:
          - no-new-privileges:true
        networks:
          - proxy
        ports:
          - "80:80"
          - "443:443"
        environment:
          - "OVH_ENDPOINT=${OVH_ENDPOINT}"
          - "OVH_APPLICATION_KEY=${OVH_AK}"
          - "OVH_APPLICATION_SECRET=${OVH_AS}"
          - "OVH_CONSUMER_KEY=${OVH_CK}"
        volumes:
          - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
          - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
          - ./traefik-data/traefik.yml:/traefik.yml:ro
          - ./traefik-data/acme.json:/acme.json
          - ./traefik-data/dynconf/:/dynconf/:ro
          - ./traefik-data/logs/:/logs/
        labels:
          - "traefik.enable=true"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.sslheader.headers.customrequestheaders.X-Forwarded-Proto=https"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik.middlewares=traefik-https-redirect"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.rule=Host(`traefikdashboard.sub-domain.domain.com`)"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.middlewares=traefik-auth"
          - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-auth.basicauth.users=${AUTH_USER}:${AUTH_PWD}"
          # Following are relative to the SSL configuration
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls=true"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.certresolver=letsencrypt"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].main=domain.com"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.tls.domains[0].sans=*.domain.com"
          - "traefik.http.routers.traefik-secure.service=api@internal"
    
    networks:
      proxy:
        external: true
```

**/home/user/traefik/traefik-data/traefik.yml**

```
global:
  sendanonymoususage: false

log:
  level: debug
  filePath: "./logs/traefik.log"

accessLog:
  filePath: "./logs/access.log"

api:
  dashboard: true
  debug: true

entryPoints:

  web:
    address: ":80"
    http:
      redirections:
        entryPoint:
          to: websecure
          scheme: https

  websecure:
    address: ":443"

serversTransport:
  insecureSkipVerify: true

providers:
  docker:
    endpoint: "unix:///var/run/docker.sock"
    exposedByDefault: false
  file:
    directory: ./dynconf/
    watch: true

certificatesResolvers:
  letsencrypt:
    acme:
      # Use the following line to use the letsenctypt's staging api
      #caServer: https://acme-staging-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory
      email: myemail@myemailprovider.com
      storage: acme.json
      keyType: EC384
      dnsChallenge:
        provider: ovh
        #disablePropagationCheck: true 
        resolvers:
          - "1.1.1.1:53"
          - "1.0.0.1:53"
```

**/home/user/traefik/traefik-data/dynconf/dynamic.yml**

```
http:

  #region routers 
  routers:

    bookstack:
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"
      rule: "Host(`bookstack.mydomain.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
        - https-redirectscheme
      tls: {}
      service: bookstack

    heimdall:
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"
      rule: "Host(`heimdall.sub-domain.domain.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - secured-chain
      tls: {}
      service: heimdall

    gitea:
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"
      rule: "Host(`gitea.domain.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
        - https-redirectscheme
      tls: {}
      service: gitea

    ... some other routers ...
  #endregion

#region services
  services:

    bookstack:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.0.1:5555"
        passHostHeader: true

    heimdall:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "https://192.168.0.2:3333"
        passHostHeader: true

    gitea:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.0.1:6666"
        passHostHeader: true

      ... some other routers ...
  #endregion

#region middleware
  middlewares:

    https-redirectscheme:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: 15552000
        customFrameOptionsValue: SAMEORIGIN
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: https

    whitelist-VPN-ONLY:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
          - "10.0.0.2/32"

    whitelist-VPN-AND-LOCAL:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
          - "10.0.0.2/32"
          - "192.168.0.0/24"

    secured-chain:
      chain:
        middlewares:
          - whitelist-VPN-ONLY
          - default-headers
          - https-redirectscheme

#endregion
```

This is currently working

What i would want and i have no success trying to obtain (i read so many posts, articles and also the traefik doc itself, and tried so much differents tries):

_ I would like to split my dynamic.yml file into multiples files, one for each service. When i did it, nothing was working.

I tried something like this, but this was not working:
**dynconf/middlewares.yml**

```
middlewares:

    https-redirectscheme:
      redirectScheme:
        scheme: https
        permanent: true

    default-headers:
      headers:
        frameDeny: true
        browserXssFilter: true
        contentTypeNosniff: true
        forceSTSHeader: true
        stsIncludeSubdomains: true
        stsPreload: true
        stsSeconds: 15552000
        customFrameOptionsValue: SAMEORIGIN
        customRequestHeaders:
          X-Forwarded-Proto: https

    whitelist-VPN-ONLY:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
          - "10.0.0.2/32"

    whitelist-VPN-AND-LOCAL:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
          - "10.0.0.2/32"
          - "192.168.0.0/24"

    secured-chain:
      chain:
        middlewares:
          - whitelist-VPN-ONLY
          - default-headers
          - https-redirectscheme
```

**dynconf/bookstack.yml**

```
http: 
  routers:

    bookstack:
      entryPoints:
        - "websecure"
      rule: "Host(`bookstack.mydomain.com`)"
      middlewares:
        - default-headers
        - https-redirectscheme
      tls: {}
      service: bookstack

   services:
    bookstack:
      loadBalancer:
        servers:
          - url: "http://192.168.0.1:5555"
        passHostHeader: true
```

_ Do i have to write the middleware section in every service file? It seems redondant to do that way...

_ I would like to have the dashboard setup outside of the docker-compose.yml file and going into the dynconf directory, like so: traefik-dashboard.yml. i think it can be done, but i cannot did it working in any of my tries.

_ Eventually, can i move also the ssl related labels from the docker-compose.yml into the dynconf folder with a file like so: ssl-config.yml ?

_ Any toughts about how i could improve/clean this setup are welcome

Thank you for helping, regardless my poor english!